# Whats the best deployment for "like" search in MVC/Azure

Tags: azure, lucene, azure-sql-database, full-text-search, sql-like

I use MVC3 on Azure, I like to have a "like" kind of search,
e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

First question: **Does Lucene support "like" search**, I tried ask this question on Google,  but it's very difficult to search the word "like" without get result like: I like to use Lucene :)

Second: **What kind of performance can I get for use SQL Azure for "like" search**, with only id(int) as key, and text(string(100)) for "like" search, and rows around 10 million. I tried seems cannot work out, always timeout. Or you can answer the question as: *I know theres a way to improve "like" search in SQL Azure.*

3rd question: Is there any other product thats works well with Azure Platform can support "like" search with reasonable performance(less than 2 seconds for above sample database)

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Azure doesn't support full text indexing so 'LIKE' is limited to the ANSI SQL operator. This is wholly inadequate for general searching. In general, on the cloud (Azure) you want to avoid using SQL for searching anyway - is is the wrong place for it from a scalability point of view.

As you suggest, a lucene-based search engine is the way to go, but I would recommend using Solr (the Apache/Java lucene server). Solr can still be hosted in Azure and you will find a lot more community support, documentation and help for it.

Answer (score 3):

Lucene does support LIKE search and there is a library specific for Lucene.NET that leverages Azure Storage for the Lucene index.  This allows you to provide a fault tolerant Lucene index that will scale well in the cloud.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Azure-Library-for-83562538

Solr is a good option, but you will have to manage the storage of the index yourself unless you extend Solr to run on Azure storage yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into implementing Solr on Azure. There's a good write up with demo's and tutorials here:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrOnWindowsAzure